# How to assign text to variable after constant time through form?

Tags: java, jquery

I need to assign a string value to a variable through a form, 10 seconds after, the form is processed.

Everything works, but how to make the form return when pressing submit?

Here is my code:

```
<h:body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function () {
        $("#text").load("/x");
    }, 1000);
</script>
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{indexBean.text}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="Ok" action="#{indexBean.storeText()}"/>
</h:form>
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="text"/>
```

```
    public void storeText(final String text) {
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                setText(text);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }.run();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand very well what was your question. But, you can try this:

```
<f:ajax event="click" render="@form" />
```

Comment: I found a solution, insted of Thread.sleep() I am using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: Oh, now I understood it. Good job.